# Implement stream with multicast that doesn't complete the underlying subject

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm implementing the cache using `BehaviorSubject` and `multicast`. The stream returned from the cache should start with HTTP request. I should also be able to force refresh the cache by triggering manually `next` on subject. The common approach with two subjects outlined by Poul Kruijt is well known and suggested everywhere. **My idea is to find a way to achieve the following using only one subject throughout lifecycle of a stream.**

It would be easy to achieve with multicast like this

```
const cache = new BehaviorSubject(null);
const shared = queryThatCompletes.pipe(multicast(cache)) as any;

// sets up subscription, waits for connect
shared.subscribe((values) => console.log(values));

// triggers http request
shared.connect();

setTimeout(() => {
  // will only emit COMPLETE from subject
  shared.subscribe((values) => console.log(values));
}, 2000);

// force refresh the cache
cache.next();
```

but since the HTTP query stream completes, the second subscription doesn't get any value, just `COMPLETE` notification from subject. This behavior is described in detail [here](https://indepth.dev/reference/rxjs/operators/multicast).

The other option is to pass a factory function instead of the subject instance like this:

```
const cache = ()=> new BehaviorSubject(null);
const shared = queryThatCompletes.pipe(multicast(cache)) as any;
```

This will re-create the subject, that will subscribe to `queryThatCompletes` and re-trigger HTTP request. But the downsides is the need to call `connect` multiple times and redundant queries.

```
const cache = () => new BehaviorSubject(null);
const shared = queryThatCompletes.pipe(multicast(cache)) as any;

// sets up subscription, waits for connect
shared.subscribe((values) => console.log(values));

// triggers http request
shared.connect();

setTimeout(() => {
// sets up subscription, waits for connect
  shared.subscribe((values) => console.log(values));

  // triggers http request
  shared.connect();
}, 2000);
```

So I simply implemented HTTP stream that doesn't complete by itself and use it like this:

```
const queryOnceButDontComplete = new Observable((observer) => {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => observer.next(data));

  return () => {};
});

const cache = new BehaviorSubject(null);
const shared = queryOnceButDontComplete.pipe(multicast(cache)) as any;

// sets up subscription, waits for connect
shared.subscribe((values) => console.log(values));

// triggers http request
shared.connect();

setTimeout(() => {
// sets up subscription, waits for connect
  shared.subscribe((values) => console.log(values));
}, 2000);
```

This works, but I'm wondering if there's a way to achieve what I want without the use of custom observable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Best would be to just use a `shareReplay(1)`:

```
const shared = queryThatCompletes.pipe(shareReplay(1));

// sets up subscription, waits for connect
shared.subscribe((values) => console.log(values));

// triggers http request
shared.connect();

setTimeout(() => {
  shared.subscribe((values) => console.log(values));
}, 2000);
```

Not entirely sure what the `subscribe` and `connect` are doing there, but if you are just returning a `HttpClient` `get` call, then you should just return the `shared` observable, and whomever subscribes first to it, will trigger the http request. No need for `connect`. Any subsequent subscriptions will wait for the request to finish or receive the last emitted value from the observable.

---

Based on your comment, let's wrap this in a service (untested):

```
@Injectable()
SomeDataService {
  readonly refresh$ = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);
  
  readonly get$ = this.httpClient.get(/*url here*/);
  
  readonly shared$ = this.refresh$.pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.get$),
    shareReplay(1)
  );

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getData(): Observable<unknown> {
    return this.shared$;
  }

  refreshData(): void {
    this.refresh$.next();
  }
}
```

Does this make sense? Basically you start with a refresh subject, which get mapped to the actual network call. On the first `getData()`, the network request gets triggered. Any call on `getData()` after that will get the cached value. Calling `refreshData` will refresh the data for any subscription

Comment: `shared.connect();` - useless

Comment: I need to be able to reload (force refresh) the subject (cache). and `share` is basically `multicast + connect`, more precisely `multicast` operator with `the factory function` and `refCount` operator applied on top of it. So that's what I'm already doing

Comment: @shutsman if you want to make a hot observable into a cold one, but I can't think of any use case. Never used it myself

Comment: @PoulKruijt, thanks, but you're using two subjects - `refresh$` and `shared$`. The solution with two subjects is easy to do and explained everywhere. That's how we do it as well. My question is whether there's any way to do it with one subject.

Comment: @MaxKoretskyi I can't think of any way. Maybe using `shareReplay({ refCount: true, bufferSize: 1 })`, but then you also need to find a way to unsubscribe any other susbcriptions to the observable. What problem are you trying to solve? As far as I can see, my answer only uses one subject (and one observable)

Comment: @PoulKruijt, thanks your your efforts! _As far as I can see, my answer only uses one subject (and one observable) _ - one is `refresh$` and the other one is created implicitly with `share`, see [here](https://indepth.dev/reference/rxjs/operators/share)

Answer (score 1):

I have made functional approach that I believe is much more simpler
it uses two observables refresh$ and the desired observable,
I hope this solution might give you some thoughts

```
 const makeRestartableCahcedObservable = (ob:Observable<any>)=>{
  const refresh$ = new BehaviorSubject(null)
  return [
    refresh$.pipe(
    switchMap(()=>ob),
    shareReplay(1)
  ),
  ()=>refresh$.next(null)
]
}

const [ob, refreshFun] = makeRestartableCahcedObservable(of('string'))

ob.subscribe(console.log)

setTimeout(()=>{refreshFun()}, 3000)
```

this basically can refresh your data with much more simpler API,
you can even wrap it with an object to make it a proxy with included refresh function

```
const makeRestartableCahcedObservable = (ob:Observable<any>)=>{
  const refresh$ = new BehaviorSubject(null)
  const wrappedOb$ = refresh$.pipe(switchMap(()=>ob),shareReplay(1))
  return {
    subscribe:(...args)=>wrappedOb$.subscribe(...args),
    pipe:(...funs)=>wrappedOb$.pipe(...funs),
    refresh:()=>refresh$.next(null)
  }
}

const ob = makeRestartableCahcedObservable(of('string'))

ob.subscribe(console.error)

setTimeout(()=>{ob.refresh()}, 3000)
```

Comment: it is the same solution as https://stackoverflow.com/a/71853916/9200941

Comment: nope this one wraps the whole thing and provides an easy encapsulated API, I've edited my answer btw

Comment: yep, Poul also has encapsulated API in SomeDataService

Comment: `SomeDataService.shared$.subscribe(), SomeDataService.refreshData()` vs `ob.subscribe, ob.refresh()`

Comment: Yes but to reuse his service you need to replicate a refresh$ for every request manually

Comment: I have encapsulated the refresh logic inside of the wrapper making more reusable

Comment: how you are going to refresh your API call?? it isnt mannually?

Comment: I mean if you have multiple requests in that service let's say
usersRefresh$, conactsRefresh$ and functions for each vs wrapping the whole refresh logic inside

Comment: lets say service `SomeDataService` exists only for this logic, no other requests

Comment: you have only one request , no matters what other are doing

Comment: so SomeDataService is not reusable in other places, ok

Comment: creating a whole service for refreshing one request VS calling a function

Comment: so, how it is going to work in separate components? how many API call will be triggered?